# Que recorta la cadena de una funcion de oracle?

Tags: visual-studio, funciones, oracle-11g

Tengo este caso:

Resulta que tengo una funcion en un paquete en oracle el cual me devuelve una cadena de 4 caracteres

:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al realizar la ejecución de la función desde visual studio con el mismo parametro de entra en el mismo servidor el resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya he probado de todo, cambiarle el tamaño de la cadena, el tipo de datos etc etc etc, pero aun me sigue cortando la cadena de salida.

Comment: Para que sea mas facil encontrar una solución a tu pregunta, trata de no sacar una captura del código, si no pegarlo en el editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione de esta forma, la explicación no la logre encontrar pero salí de ese lió, pero pensaría que es algo del servidor de aplicación ya que solo en desarrollo se presentaba esta inconsistencia.

```
            SQL.Append("Select PAQUETE.Funcion('"+Parametro+"') from dual");

            CMD = CNX.CreateCommand();
            CMD.Connection = CNX;
            CMD.CommandText = SQL.ToString();
            CMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            if (CNX.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                CNX.Open();

            string a = CMD.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            return a;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            CNX.Close();
        }
    }`
```